# TypeScript: generic function parameter name

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

So I'm aware I can have a generic key name in an object like this:

```
type A<B extends string> = { [C in B]?: string }

const c: A<"a" | "b"> = {
    "a": "example",
}
```

I was wondering with parameters being strings, if I could do something similar with them. Something like this:

```
type A<B extends string> = ([C in B]?: string) => string

const c: A<"a" | "b"> = (a: string) => string
```

Of course, the second example doesn't work, but I wonder if there is a way to do so.

Comment: Parameter names are intentionally unobservable to the type system (although they are observable to how types are *displayed*).  The type `(a: string) => string` and `(z: string) => string` are identical and there's no principled way to translate between those and the string literal types `"a"` or `"z"`.  Requests for such features tend to be declined (see [ms/TS#31627](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31627)).  So the answer is "no".  Does that fully address your question? If so I could write up an answer with sources; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Side note: "with parameters being strings" isn't true, really.  In what way are parameters strings?  Maybe you're conflating the code itself (where *everything* is a string, because code is written in text) with what the code represents (where the `a` in `(a: string) => string` is a dummy parameter identifier)?

Comment: @jcalz Ah! I was not aware they did not matter. I assumed they did since the parameter name is required. As to the side note, I've seen someone extract the parameter name from a function before, it was very ugly, but I thought that if you can extract it, you must be able to set it (Or at least that's the case for most javascript constructs which is why you can have things like jsfuck https://badacadabra.github.io/Understanding-JSFuck/).

Comment: You've seen someone extract it where?  Not in the TypeScript type system, surely.  Maybe you mean from JS code?   Yes, in JS you can convert a function to a string and then parse that string... but that's well outside anything TypeScript would want to support or try to model.  Anyway, I'll probably write up an answer here when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit to @jcalz

Parameter names are intentionally unobservable to the type system (although they are observable to how types are displayed). The type `(a: string) => string` and `(z: string) => string` are identical and there's no principled way to translate between those and the string literal types `"a"` or `"z"`.

In essence, the language requires the parameter name as part of the syntax, and an editor is able to display the name to the user, but they are equivalent nevertheless.

On top of the name not mattering, it is impossible to do what the question specifies with the current typescript implementation.